# How do I setup Django on Virtualhost?

Tags: apache, laravel-5, django-rest-framework, react-redux

How do I setup apache2 virtual host with Django app. Currently I am using Django by "python manage.py runserver". I need to host Django app remotely.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don´t add tags of everything you use in your project or of related topics. Only use the tags which are directly connected to the question (Your current question would only indicate the tags [tag:apache2] and [tag:django]). Also try adding more information to your question. I recommend you read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question based on the information there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and replace the php based virtualhost configuration which points to `/var/www/html`  with the one that points to wsgi.py of your project.

Example Virtual Host Configuration [(read more)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

```
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/mysite.com/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/mysite.com/static/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```